# Why are there suddenly 25 [untagged] questions, and what should we do with them?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

I just noticed there are 25 [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions. Normally, this number is (very close to) zero; now and then, a question gets migrated to Stack Overflow and loses its tags but it's usually [tagged rather quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54113147/revisions). Most questions are old, (too) broad, but deemed moderately useful by the community (judging by the number of upvotes). Two examples:

- [What does a Software Architect do and what programs do they use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843610/what-does-a-software-architect-do-and-what-programs-do-they-use)
- [Lifespan of Software: How often do you expect to do start from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360297/lifespan-of-software-how-often-do-you-expect-to-do-start-from-scratch)

How did this happen? I do not see anything in the questions' history which indicate a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) gone haywire or something like that.

A follow-up question would be what to do with them. Some of them can easily be tagged (e.g. [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5148886/4751173)); that's what I usually do when there are only a few of them. This case *feels* different, even though the number of questions involved is so low that bumping them over the course of a 24 hour period would not be noticeable.

<sub>FWIW, there's another site in the network with [550 untagged questions](https://serverfault.com/tags/untagged). Most of those are locked and can't be retagged.</sub>

Comment: There are now 0 (zero) questions tagged with the paradoxical [tag:untagged] tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These would be fallout from a tag burnination, the most recent one I can think of that might apply is the [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) tag where there were quite a few questions with high view counts from the early days of the site. When that tag got removed I went through the list and deleted those questions with low votes and views.

Despite our best efforts a few questions that only have a single tag get missed and end up [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

If this has happened then it's usually a sign that the question is off topic - the first question you linked to certainly appears to be from the title alone.

If you think that the question is on topic then just edit and add some relevant tags.

If you can't think of any relevant tags then that's another sign the question is off topic. In this cases vote to close (if it's not already closed), or vote to delete if it's closed.

Comment: All these questions are already closed for over 3 days (>10K users can cast delete votes), and look off-topic and unsalvageable to me. I've cast my max amount of delete votes for today, and hope others will as well.

Comment: Heh, forgot that these are closed long enough that I can vote to delete as well.